# running craftyjs (via canvas) and redrawing figuers creates weird lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, craftyjs, visual-artifacts

We are working on a browser/JavaScript based game where sprites are regulary redrawn, however doing so creates weird lines after each redraw. We could of course let the hole view redraw after each frame however that would kill performance quite badly. Is there any other way to fix this?

[image]

So we are using crafty to draw in isometric view a number of sprites on a canvas, when deleting these sprites weird lines appear and we are looking for a way to net let them appear.

Any suggestion would be helpful as are comments re

Comment: Do you try to reproducate' this problem with each canvas level? (eg. slice to layers, and re-test the drawing with each individual layer without the others). Debug tools what say? show any error (console, js debugger or anything? maybe a js waypont-tracer-debugger?)

Comment: What version of Crafty.js are you using? Because that a bug similar was solved in 6.1 of crafty.